# Capture events generated by control tabs

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to capture events generated by control tabs from library.

Please refer to this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selected(v=vs.110).aspx
c# UWP

It shows events that is generated by control tabs.

Comment: Vikash, could you please explain your problem more clearly rather than link to the library's documentation

Comment: It's *Tab Control* and the link is to the wrong class. You tagged the question with `UWP` and yet the link is to the Winforms control.

Comment: In any case, the docs show what the events are and how to handle them. You could just double click on the relevant control in the Visual Studio Properties window, although that would violate the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Tabs in UWP applications [are described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tabs-pivot). As you see, you *don't* handle events. You bind the control's ItemsSource to the ViewModels it will display. You bind the `SelectedItem` property to the ViewModel property that sets or gets the selected item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved following problem by capturing click event and checking for control tabs as

```
if (item is TabControl)
            {
                ((TabControl)item).SelectedIndexChanged += TabChangeHandler;
            }
```

and in function TabChangeHandler I have increased pageinstance

```
public void TabChangeHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PageInstance = PageInstance + 1;
            SnapShotInstance = -1;
        }
```